# jquery showModalDialog center moves when item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery modal window which I show with the following code

```
    function ViewProfile(Profiles) {
        var url = 'Add.aspx?DashboardView=1&CloseOnUpdate=1&ProfileID=' + Profiles

        $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');

        //calculate height
        var winW = $(window).width() - 50;
        var winH = $(window).height() - 50;

        $.showModalDialog({
            url: url,
            height: winH,
            width: winW,
            position: { my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window },
            scrollable: true,
            closeClass: 'ui-icon-circle-close',
            onClose: enableScroll
        });
    }

    function enableScroll()
    {
        $('body').removeClass('stop-scrolling');
    }
```

I execute the code with a span onclick even like this

```
<span onclick='ViewProfile(4)' class='btn btn-sm btn-info'>View</span>
```

The span is located inside of a grid (a custom grid from Obout), when a user scrolls all the way down a window and clicks on a span, it centers the modal window perfectly, but after about a second it jumps off place. At first I thought it was the window that was jumping off place but noticed the scroll position is now off, therefore the IE/Chrome window is the one that moved, not the modal window. Has anyone experienced this? Any ideas how to fix it?